# How to keep session with HttpUrlConnection?

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, cookiemanager

I'm using `HttpUrlConnection` to perform some http request and I need to keep a session alive.

I read the doc which just say to add

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();  
CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
```

but it does not say where.

Should I add this every time I create a `HttpUrlConnection` and do a request? I can't find any example...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CookieHandler.setDefault() sets the system-wide cookie handler. You should call it once.

Comment: Ok, I put it on the `onCreate` of a class extending `Application`